# Doubly Linked List fails to add or delete valid entries

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I've run it many times. I tried fixing my deleteNode() and addNode(), but it did not work. The output showed me that it failed to add some valid entries in my list, which resulted in failing to delete these valid entries. Someone please help me find the errors... I think either my isEmpty() is wrong or the addNode got messed up.

```
// Add nodes and makes it work in any cases: backward/forward
bool LinkedList::addNode(int id, string str) {
    bool result = false;
    if (id >= 0 && !(idExists(id))) {
        Node *current = head;
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->data.data = str;
        temp->data.id = id;
        temp->forward = NULL;
        temp->back = NULL;

        // Kinds of adding cases
        if(head == NULL) {          // Check if list is empty
            addHead(temp, current);
            result = true;
        } else {
            while(temp->data.id > current->data.id && current->forward != NULL) {
                current = current->forward;
            }
            // Backward
            if(current->back == NULL) {
                if(temp->data.id > current->data.id) {
                    if(current->forward == NULL) {
                        addTail(temp, current);
                    } else {
                        addMiddle(temp, current);
                    }
                } else {
                    addHead(temp, current);
                }
                result = true;
            // Forward
            }else if(current->forward == NULL) {
                if (temp->data.id > current->data.id) {
                    addTail(temp, current);
                } else {
                    addMiddle(temp, current);
                }
                result = true;
            }else {
                if(temp->data.id > current->data.id) {
                    addMiddle(temp, current);
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void LinkedList::addHead(Node *temp, Node *current) {
    if (head != NULL){
        temp->forward = current;
        current->back = temp;
        head = temp;
    } else {
        head = temp;
    }
}

void LinkedList::addMiddle(Node *temp, Node *current) {
    temp->forward = current;
    temp->back = current->back;
    current->back->forward = temp;
    current->back = temp;
}

void LinkedList::addTail(Node *temp, Node *current) {
    current->forward = temp;
    temp->back = current;
}

// Delete list
bool LinkedList::deleteNode(int id){
    bool result = false;
    if (idExists(id)) {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current->forward != NULL && current->data.id != id) {
            current = current->forward;
        }
        if (current->data.id == id && current->forward == NULL) {
            if (current->back == NULL) {        // Delete head
                delete current;
                head = NULL;
            } else {        // delete tail
                deleteTail(current);
            }
            result = true;
        } else if (current->data.id == id) {
            if (current->back == NULL)
                deleteHead(current);
            else            // delete middle
                deleteMiddle(current);
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


// Helper delete functions
void LinkedList::deleteHead(Node *current) {
    head = current->forward;
    head->back = NULL;
    delete current;
}

void LinkedList::deleteMiddle(Node *current) {
        current->back->forward = current->forward;
        current->forward->back = current->back;
        delete current;
}

void LinkedList::deleteTail(Node *current) {
        current->back->forward = NULL;
        delete current;
}

bool LinkedList::getNode(int id, Data *data) {
    bool didGetNode = false;

    if (idExists(id)) {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current->forward != NULL && current->data.id != id) {
            current = current->forward;
        }
        data->id = current->data.id;
        data->data = current->data.data;
        didGetNode = true;
    }

    return didGetNode;
}

// Check whether or not the id exists
bool LinkedList::idExists(int id){
    bool exists = false;
    if (head != NULL){
        Node *current = head;
        while (current->forward != NULL && current->data.id != id) {
            current = current->forward;
        }
        if (current->data.id == id) {
            exists = true;
        }
    }
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need that many cases in your add? Can you explain (to yourself) why you need each and every one of those branches and in which cases they'll get hit?

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something that can be compiled to verify your issues and something that provides definitions of `Data` and `Node`, etc..

Comment: Where is `head` defined.

Comment: The amount of code to do the job of inserting no-duplicate nodes, or deleting nodes by id, from your linked list, is about 10x more than it needs to be. Design first, *then* code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be passing a pointer to a pointer (**) or a pointer to a reference (*&) in functions where you are wanting to make a change to what the address of the node is containing. I hope that this helps you visualize it.

For example:

```
struct Node { };

void setNull1(Node* temp)
{
    temp = nullptr;
}

void setNull2(Node** temp)
{
    (*temp) = nullptr;
}

void setNull3(Node*& temp)
{
    temp = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    Node* tmp = new Node;

    setNull1(tmp);
    if (tmp == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "NULLPTR";
    } // tmp is not nullptr

    Node* tmp1 = new Node;
    setNull2(&tmp1);
    if (tmp1 == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "NULLPTR";
    } // tmp1 is nullptr

    Node* tmp2 = new Node;
    setNull3(tmp2);
    if (tmp2 == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "NULLPTR";
    } // tmp2 is nullptr
}
```

You should also consider writing `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: How this is applicable to the OP's C++ class, `LinkedList`, where all members already have (and use) direct access to the `head` member, escapes me.

Comment: For some reason I thought that he was using a tail pointer, too. But knowledge of the above concept will help the OP to simplify his code.